# Wordpress quick contact search render glitch

Tags: wordpress

[image]

I have been trying to fettle this for a few hours - when quick searching for a contact on Wordpress, the results appear behind the Wordpress admin menu.  I can't see anyone else who has reported this issue, is it a known problem?

Latest Shoreditch enabled (and only happens with Shoreditch enabled), Civi 5.10.0, WP 5.0.3

Thank you!

(PS, personal data shown in this image is a fake contact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/ instead to style Civi in WP.

It says shoreditch extension is optional https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder. I also just tested and Mosaico still works.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that plugin. Mosaico seems to be happiest with the Shoreditch plugin installed and enabled, but under the resources & URLs section, with Shoreditch *not* enabled for the wider site.

Comment: I use CiviCRM Admin Utilities with Shoreditch and Mosaico. I also use Keyboard Accessible Menu (uk.squiffle.kam), which is expected to be merged into core. See also https://civicrm.org/blog/danaskallman/wordpress-admin-styles-for-civicrm-with-wordpress.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also have Shoreditch disabled in Resources & URLs.

Comment: This plugin solved my problems, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the extension page https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch says that Shoreditch is CMS independent, the release notes https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch say that Drupal is a requirement, so I don't think you can expect it to work.  Much as I would love to have it on Wordpress.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. Hopefully Mosaico will behave without it